# Hololens Emulator app zzz

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I have been following several tutorials from Microsoft on the Hololens, from the real basic 100 ( creating a Cube ) to the 101E.

However when deploying to the Hololens it doesn't troughs a error, all succeed, but when starting the App it shows a white screen and then zzz with a Moon "emoticon".

The only error i'm getting is the one attached. However developer license is active. And i also renewed it, but is that related? Don't know.

Log file:

```
> 
3>------ Deploy started: Project: Origami, Configuration: Release x86 ------
3>Deploying to Phone Internal Storage...
3>Creating a new clean layout...
3>Copying files: Total 48 mb to layout...
3>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
3>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00/x86, app package version 14.0.24123.0 is not currently installed.
3>Framework: Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0/x86, app package version 1.0.23819.0 is not currently installed.
3>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00/x86, app package version 14.0.24123.0 is not currently installed.
3>Installing missing frameworks...
3>Registering the application to run from layout...
3>Deployment complete (0:00:05,557). Full package name: "Origami_1.0.0.0_x86__sx6pycx103f58"
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image: Error within Visual Studio 2015 update 3]

[image: Application Emulator zzz]

Answer (score 0):

There are several scenarios which produce this error. Here are a few ways, from my expetience, that may solve this issue:

- In the Package.appxmanifest, find the line specifying TargetDeviceFamily and change Name="Windows.Universal" to Name="Windows.Holographic" and MaxVersionTested="10.0.10240.0" to MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.0".

  - Go to the device portal and shutdown the instance of the app if it is running.
  - Try uninstalling the app from the emulator before installing it.

The hololens can be quite tedious to work with at first, but once you get the hang of it, it is a wonderful technology!